# Attempting to stop server on UWAWP says "access denied" and simultaneously crashes all my open Chrome tabs

Tags: apache, crash, webserver

When I attempt to 'stop server' on UWAWP I receive an "access denied" message, but it seems like it does close properly.

However, this simultaneously crashes all my open Chrome tabs.

What's happening?

I'd expect a silent close of the server.